# Split a String to a String[] so that each element is maximum 100 characters and ends in a space

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, character

How do i do this? I tried something like this but I do not seem to be able to get any further.

```
public void speak(String text)
{
    String[] textArray = text.split(" ");
    System.out.println(text);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    int index = 0;

        while(builder.length() < 99)
        {
            builder.append(textArray[index] + " ");
            index++;
        } 

    System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```

EDIT:
 I need every String to be seperate String that is only a 100 chars long. So i will need each String in an Array or an Arralist for example.

Comment: What's wrong with what you're doing?  Hmm, maybe I see.  The `while` loop you have should be the inner loop.  You need an outerloop to contain it to go through the entire `textArray`.

Comment: Yeah and everytime I try that i get an OutOfBounds Error. Could you maybe make a quick example of how you would do it?

Comment: So, space between every word, and if a word would take the current line over 100 characters, it should start a new line?

Comment: @nhgrif your answear that is now gone was the most accurate but it keept giving me an OutOfBounds Exception unfortunaly.

Comment: I just undeleted it.  And made some fixes that should address a couple of issues.  Give it another try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
int index = 0;
while(index < textArray.length()) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    if(textArray[index].length() >= 99) {
        build.append(textArray[index]);
        index++;
    } else {
        while(builder.length() < 99 - (textArray[index].length())) {
            builder.append(textArray[index] + " ");
            index++;
            if(!(index < textArray.length()) {
                break;
            }
    }
    lines.add(builder.toString());
}
```

The inner `while` loop will do what it's already doing in your code, build a single line, less than 100 characters long, adding a space after each word.

Then, when we would go over 100 characters, append a new line character to the string, and continue on.

---

As a note, this bit of code:

```
if(textArray[index].length() >= 99) {
    build.append(textArray[index]);
    index++;
}
```

will handle the (should-be-rare) case of a word which is longer than 99 characters (no spaces).  As written, it will keep this word completely together on the line, and may result in a line longer than 100 characters.  If you want different behavior, then look to this bit of code.

But words with more than 99 characters should probably be pretty rare and this may be a complete non-issue.

Comment: I was probably downvoted for the messed up `for` loop, which I've quickly corrected.

Comment: Does not work properly; will stop printing additional elements and instead loop infinitely after the total is > 100 characters. -1

Comment: @Saposhiente Fixed.  Per questioner's comment on another answer, he wants individual lines in some sort of array.

Comment: Still loops infinitely with some inputs, and is now overcomplicated. Look at my answer for how to do it.

Comment: Can you explain to me how it loops infinitely?  Which loop, inner or outer?  What makes it loop infinitely?

Comment: while (index < constant) { while(condition that might be false) {/*code that might not be executed*/} /*code that doesn't change the value of index or cause the other condition to become true*/}

Comment: Can you give me an example of input that would cause this infinite loop?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42718/discussion-between-saposhiente-and-nhgrif)

Comment: @Saposhiente The answer was deleted (by me), I made some fixes and have now undeleted it.  All of the others answers were just grabbing 100 characters and ignoring words (mine was the only that addressed this)... so anyway, it's a little more complicated, but apparently the problem was more complicated than you originally realized.

Comment: Firstly, my answer did not ignore words. Secondly, the poster has clarified the requirements once again such that whether or not your code loops (it is waay too overcomplicated at this point), it still won't produce the correct output; using textArray = text.split(" "); is incorrect for this problem. If you want to discuss why your code is overcomplicated in its own right, please do so in chat.

Comment: Can you explain how my answer, which the original question-asker commented was the most accurate (but was having an error that I've sense fixed) is giving incorrect output?  Please, tell me more about how you know better than him what the correct output is... and explain to me why my answer gets a downvote from you, but other answers in which you comment "gives incorrect output" don't get downvotes.

Comment: And your original answer DID ignore words... hence the original question-asker's comment "BUT the strings have to end in a natural space!"

Comment: Thx @nhgrif! This does exactly what I want!

Comment: @user2298680 This is inefficient, looping thru the entire string to split and then looping again to put things back together. My answer only accesses on average the number of characters per word, times the length of the string, divided by 200; for standard English, that is 40x faster. Other discussion belongs in chat.

Answer (score 0):

For wrapping text, rather than focusing on the spaces, focus on the 100 character limit. For most text, spaces will occur far more often than once per 100 characters.

```
public void speak(String text) {
    while(text.length() > 100) {
        int nextSpace = text.lastIndexOf(" ", 99);
        if (nextSpace == -1) { //no spaces for 100 characters
            System.out.println(text.substring(0, 100));//give as many characters as possible, then split anyway
            text = text.substring(100);
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println(text.substring(0, nextSpace));
        text = text.substring(nextSpace + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Comment: This just gives me an ArrayList with everyword as It's own element in the array.

Comment: @user2298680 That's what your comment on another post said that you wanted. If you want the string, replace result.add(...) with builder.append(... + " ")

Comment: I do not follow you on that one. Something you could make clearer in code?

Comment: @user2298680 This code takes the strings from TextArray which were the result of splitting text at the spaces. It moves these Strings into an ArrayList, which is what you said you want. (If this is not what you want, please clarify and tell us what your expected output is.) While moving them into the ArrayList, it checks whether they are 100 characters long or longer. If so, it splits them into strings that are each 100 characters long or shorter.

Comment: I want the Strings in the arraylist to be as close to a 100 characters long as possible. BUT the strings have to end in a natural space!

Comment: @user2298680 Oh, I see, you want to make a program that wraps text in a 100-character-wide display. Did that. You should update the question to make your intention clearer; my original program did meet your original requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is late and a bit inefficient but I think it does the job nicely.

```
public class StringSplitter
{ 
  private int maxCharactersPerLine = 100;

  public List<string> GetTextLines(string text)
  { 
    var result = new List<string>();

    if(text.Length <= this.maxCharactersPerLine)
    {
      result.Add(text);
      return result;
    }

    string words[] = text.Split(new[]{' '}, StringSplittingOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    //accumolator, describes a line of text up to maximum character length.
    string temp = string.Empty; 

    //this is so that we don't append an empty space on each new line.
    bool isBeginingWord = true;

    foreach(var word in words)
    {
      //there is a possibility that a text line has more than maximum
      //consecutive characters without having a space. This is edge case. 
      if(temp.Length > this.maxCharactersPerLine)
      {
        result.Add(temp);
        continue;
      }

      //if adding the next word in the list will exceed the 
      //maximum characters per line of text
      if((temp + " " + word).Length > this.maxCharactersPerLine)
      {
        result.Add(temp);      //add the accumolator to the list.
        temp = "";             //reset the accumolator
        isBeginingWord= true;  //reset beginning of word flag.
        continue;
      }

      //adding the next word from the list results in accumolator still
      //still shorter than the maximum characters per line of text.
      if(isBeginingWord)
      {
        temp = word;
        isBeginingWord = false;
        continue;
      }

      temp = temp + " " + word;
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible with regular expression, it needs less code:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("[\\s\\S]{99}");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(s);
ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<>();

int lastFound=0;
while (matcher.find()){
    list.add(matcher.group()+" ");
    lastFound = matcher.end();      
}
list.add(s.substring(lastFound));
```

If you mean something else just comment! May be you need to add more patterns in your string has tabs, new line and other special chars.

Comment: Does not produce wanted output; see comments on my answer.