# C#: How do i split a string on a whitespace after 100 characters have been reached

Tags: c#, string, foreach, split

I have got the following code but it doesn't seem to do what it should do. The code at the foreach loop needs to go through each character up to the 100th character. But it appears the loop runs on, it doesn't stop. How do I fix that?

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
string[] a = MainRichTextBox.Text.Split('.');

while (a[0].Length > 0 || a[0].Length != 0)
{
    NumberOfChars = a[0].Length;

    if (NumberOfChars < 100)
    {
        r = NumberOfChars;

    }

    else if (NumberOfChars == 100)
    {
        r = 100;
    }

    else if (NumberOfChars > 100)
    {
        r = 100;
    }

    decimal numberOfTweetsUnRounded = a[0].Length / 100M;

    if (numberOfTweetsUnRounded == 0)
    {
        numberOfTweetsUnRounded = 1;
    }

    int numberOfTweetsRounded = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(numberOfTweetsUnRounded));
    int numberOfSpaces = 0;
    int indexOfSpaces = 0;
    int indexOfCChars = 0;
    int indexPointOfSplit = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfTweetsRounded; i++)
    {
        if (r == 100)
        {
            //The problem occurs here. This loop doesn't stop at the 100th character.
            foreach (char c in a[0].Substring(0, 100))
            {
                indexOfCChars++;
                if (c == ' ')
                {
                    indexOfSpaces++;
                    indexPointOfSplit = indexOfCChars;
                    MessageBox.Show(indexPointOfSplit.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        //When I split the string, it doesn't work. It gives an error of the index being outside the range.
        string breakOff = a[0].Substring(0, indexPointOfSplit);
        builder.Append(breakOff).Append(" " + textBox1.Text).Append(" [" + i + "/" + numberOfTweetsRounded + "] " + "\r\n");

        showNow = builder.ToString();
    }

    a[0] = a[0].Remove(0, indexPointOfSplit);
    builder.Clear();
    NumberOfChars = a[0].Length;
    MainRichTextBox.AppendText(showNow);


    //When I split the string, it doesn't work. It gives an error of the index being outside the range.
    string breakOff = a[0].Substring(0, indexPointOfSplit);
    builder.Append(breakOff).Append(" " + textBox1.Text).Append(" [" + i + "/" + numberOfTweetsRounded + "] " + "\r\n");

    showNow = builder.ToString();
}

a[0] = a[0].Remove(0, indexPointOfSplit);
builder.Clear();
NumberOfChars = a[0].Length;
MainRichTextBox.AppendText(showNow);
```

Comment: What's it stopping at? Have you tried to step through the code? If you  are testing with a string less than 100, your `a[0].Substring(0, 100)` is going to blow up. There's nothing wrong with that `foreach`. It will return you a 100 length string if the Substring() doesn't throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: There is already the same question with an answer in Java. I'm sure you'd be able to take something from that solution: [Split a `String` to a `String[]` so that each element is maximum 100 characters and ends in a space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445947/split-a-string-to-a-string-so-that-each-element-is-maximum-100-characters-and?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I stepped throught he code, and and it appears to exit that loop, I made some slight changes to your code:

```
  while (a[0].Length > 0 || a[0].Length != 0)
        {
            NumberOfChars = a[0].Length;
            if (NumberOfChars < 100)
            {
                r = NumberOfChars;

            }
            else if (NumberOfChars == 100)
            {
                r = 100;
            }
            else if (NumberOfChars > 100)
            {
                r = 100;
            }

            decimal numberOfTweetsUnRounded = a[0].Length/100M; 
            if (numberOfTweetsUnRounded == 0)
            {
                numberOfTweetsUnRounded = 1;
            }

            int numberOfTweetsRounded = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(numberOfTweetsUnRounded));
            int numberOfSpaces = 0;
            int indexOfSpaces = 0;
            int indexPointOfSplit = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfTweetsRounded; i++)
            {
                if (r == 100)
                {
                    string firstItem = a[0].Substring(0, 100);
                    for (int pos = 0; pos < firstItem.Length; pos++)
                    {
                        if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(firstItem[pos]))
                            continue;
                        indexOfSpaces++;
                        indexPointOfSplit = pos;
                    }
                }
                //When I split the string, it doesn't work. It gives an error of the index being outside the range.
                string breakOff = a[0].Substring(0, indexPointOfSplit);
            }
            a[0] = a[0].Remove(0, indexPointOfSplit);
            builder.Clear();
            NumberOfChars = a[0].Length;
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to initialize `indexOfCChars` to 0 before the `foreach` loop. Since it can have a value greater than 0 before the loop, it can be incremented to a value greater than 100 during the loop. This makes it *appear* as if the loop body is executing over 100 times, which is not likely.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set indexOfCChars = 0 after your if (r == 100) statement.

```
 if (r == 100)
    {

        indexOfCChars = 0

        //The problem occurs here. This loop doesn't stop at the 100th character.
        foreach (char c in a[0].Substring(0, 100))
        {
            indexOfCChars++;
            if (c == ' ')
            {
                indexOfSpaces++;
                indexPointOfSplit = indexOfCChars;
                MessageBox.Show(indexPointOfSplit.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```