# tExtractRegexFields Talend, using regex to seperate column into multiple columns by length

Tags: java, regex, extract, talend

I have a job that has a column that is unbounded coming from an xml file and the length of the column can exceed more than 4000 characters, however, this is the maximum length of Oracle varchar column. I need to be able to use the `tExtractRegexFields` component in Talend to separate the columns every 3000-4000 characters into a separate column.

I however, am not good with Regex and am having some trouble.

The text is generally formatted like this:

```
"<p>#Principal Responsibilities: </p>
<p>INSERT EXTREMELY LONG DESCRIPTION HERE</p>"
```

I tried using something like this:

```
"([a-zA-Z0-9]{0,4000})"
```

but I was having no luck, it was only capturing 1 word.

Job is set up like this:

```
tFileInputXML------>tExtractRegexFields----->tMap------tOracleOutput
```

I know it is something simple I am missing, but I just cant figure out what!

Comment: I do not know your use case but have you considered using [`CLOB`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefclob.html) instead?

Comment: I cannot use CLOB, has to be VARCHAR2

Comment: What about `[\\w+]{0,4000}`?

Comment: that still only gives me the first word :/

Comment: Why? `+` stands for **one or more**.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: @PM77-1 As I explained in DaaaahWhoosh's answer, that's still only capturing one group of characters. You're then leaving the rest uncaptured. At that point you may as well have substringed it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture more than alphanumeric characters. Try "([.]{0,4000})", that should get you everything, assuming Talend accepts the period to mean any character.
Alternatively, you could accept "([a-zA-Z0-9 ]{0, 4000})" (note the space), which should get you more than one word, but probably not anything after the first punctuation.

Comment: This still only captures the first instance of something between 0 and 4000 characters. Regex with non dynamic capture groups is not the solution here.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I guess this one is harder than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd seriously reconsider what you're trying to do here.

If you're trying to store an entire XML document in a single field then you might be much better off either storing it as an XMLTYPE datatype in your Oracle database or using tXMLMap in Talend to parse the XML and put each element and attribute into separate columns.

On the other hand, if this is a single, huge element of your XML document then you might also be better storing it as a CLOB.

If you absolutely must persist with this idea of keeping it in a VARCHAR column for whatever reason (and I'd be absolutely certain that that's what you need to do because it will tank your database's performance) then you're going to need to use a tJavaRow to split this into chunks. The tExtractRegexField component will only output the match groups that you capture and there's no way (that I know of) of dynamically capturing groups in some recursive manner that Talend can use.

I don't think you can output into a dynamic schema with the tJavaRow (or at least never seen it done) so you'll have to profile your data to get a rough idea of how many columns you need to cover all your data (so if you are splitting it into fields of 255 each and your maximum field length is 25500 then you need 100 columns). From here you then want to add all of those columns to the tJavaRow's output schema and then use some code that looks a little like [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20446028/2291321) but modify it to link each String[] to your output field. You might need to make this a for loop and explicitly point each element of the String[] to each `output_row.column`.

As an example with some **horrible code** that is absolutely going to be some of the **worst performing code** you'll ever see but demonstrates the principle:

```
String col1 = "";
String col2 = "";
String col3 = "";
String col4 = "";
String col5 = "";
String[] data = input_row.hugeData.split("");

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        // Do nothing, it's an empty element
    } else if (i < 10) {
        col1 += data[i];
    } else if (i < 20) {
        col2 += data[i];
    } else if (i < 30) {
        col3 += data[i];
    } else if (i < 40) {
        col4 += data[i];
    } else if (i < 50) {
        col5 += data[i];
    }
}


// Finally output the chunks to individual columns
output_row.col1 = col1;
output_row.col2 = col2;
output_row.col3 = col3;
output_row.col4 = col4;
output_row.col5 = col5;
```

With input strings of:

```
"12345678901234567890123456789012345"
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
"1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890"
```

I get an output of:

```
|=--------+----------+----------+----------+------=|
|col1     |col2      |col3      |col4      |col5   |
|=--------+----------+----------+----------+------=|
|123456789|0123456789|0123456789|012345    |       |
|abcdefghi|jklmnopqrs|tuvwxyz   |          |       |
|123456789|0qwertyuio|pasdfghjkl|zxcvbnm123|4567890|
'---------+----------+----------+----------+-------'
```

You'll obviously want to rewrite this code so it's something more like the answer I linked above (although you don't have to care about words being longer than 99 characters) and isn't O(MG).

Comment: Downstream system APIs Im told cannot accept that data type. Also, no I am not attempting to store an entire XML in 1 field. The XML is being separated into 25 tables, each with a varying amount of columns. The source system of the XML does not put a limit on characters for the field in question. I am trying to prevent future loss of information or errors if data in excess of 4000 characters is passed by breaking that field up. I will look into your suggestion though.

Comment: I've added some hideous example code so you can see if it works for your purpose. Use it sparingly and then rework the whole thing to not be awful.

Comment: I still think you'd be better off storing anything that could be potentially that large as a CLOB (it should only be XMLTYPE if it represents a complete document). Downstream systems should be expecting something potentially huge and simply request it as such.

Comment: If it was up to me, I'd use CLOB as well. But, I was asked to investigate options that don't do that by the powers above me :P

Answer (score 0):

How about using a tJavaRow like:

```
int colNum = 10;
int splitAt = 4000;
String data = input_row.line;
String[] columns = new String[colNum]; 
for(int i = 0 ; i<= colNum && data.length() > 0; i++) {  
  columns[i] = data.substring(0,data.length() > splitAt ? splitAt : data.length()); 
  data       = data.substring(  data.length() > splitAt ? splitAt : data.length(),data.length()); 
}
if(input_row.data.length != 0) { throw new Exception("Not enough output columns"); }
output_row.col1 = columns[1];
output_row.col2 = columns[2];
output_row.col3 = columns[3];
```